# "which...come from" VS "where... come"

Tags: subordinate-clauses

> 1. let's talk about the country where you come from.
> 2. let's talk about the country where you come.
> 3. let's talk about the country which you come from.

I am not certain which one is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options 1 and 3 are grammatically correct, both can be used to describe place of origin. Option 2 is incorrect. Where gives it a broader feeling of where the person comes from. Which points out a more specific place.